# Контейнеры Java

Tags: java, методы, ввод, контейнеры

программисты! Пытаюсь разобраться с контейнерами. Программа, используя метод add добавляет в массив из строк(изначально n=0 по размерности) заданное значение, через класс контейнер. Моя проблема в том, что при использовании моего метода add несколько раз- массив из строк записывает только последнюю строку, игнорируя прошлую. По сути метод не может создать массив более чем 1 элемент.

```
class Container {
private String[] strings;
private String[] newStrings;


 public Container(int n) {
   this.strings= new String[n];

        }
```

Метод add

```
 public void add(String value)
{
    this.newStrings = this.strings.clone();
    this.strings = new String[this.newStrings.length + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < this.newStrings.length; i++) {
        this.strings[i] = this.newStrings[i];
    }
    this.strings[(this.strings.length - 1)] = value;
    this.newStrings = null;
    //проверка получаемого значения
    for (int i=0; i<this.strings.length; i++){
        System.out.println(this.strings[i]);
    }
}
```

И вызов методов add:

```
 switch (option) {
          case "A":
                cont.add("Привет!");
                break;
          case "B":
              cont.add("Как твои дела?");
              break;
          case "C":
                cont.StringtoString(strings, n);
                break;

      }
```

То есть нажав А и В должен создаться массив, в котором есть 2 строки "Привет!" и "Как твои дела?" а на деле мой код просто пишет либо 1-е либо 2-е.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: метод `add` [работает](https://ideone.com/dCxupW), проблема скорее всего в коде, окружающем `switch` (предположу что вы пересоздаете `cont` на каждой итерации цикла).

Comment: Спасибо, буду думать еще

Comment: при чем тут контейнеры?

Comment: один ньюанс, где вы создавали объект из класса Contanier? Судя по всему, вы один раз в начале его создали, и задали фиксированный размер.

Comment: по этому отрывку кода мало что понятно

Comment: и лучше не создавать функцию в том же классе, что и main - это по ООПэшному

Comment: учу предмет ООП, если что) Да, вы правы, создал вначале и дал фиксированный размер